# Keeping an instance variable as an instance variable, not its contents

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have only a vague idea on phrasing this, so question as needed:

I have a set of values I'm passing in my rails controller on a regular basis to a widget that differs slightly from page to page, from what I pass to it. This is is starting to get unwieldy for every controller, so I added a small class to help concatenate that process a bit (basic starting gist below).

```
#return dashcontroller hash from more succinct cues
module DashControl
  class DashControl

    attr_accessor :title, :instance, :actions 

    def initialize(title='default title', instance='default instance', actions={})
      @title = title
      @instance = instance
      initialize_actions(actions)
    end

    def initialize_actions(actions)
      actions.kind_of?(Hash) ? @actions = actions : initialize_tag(actions)
    end

    def initialize_tag(tag)
      case tag
      when :manage_default
        @actions = {:statusactions => [], 
                    :formactions => [ ['#tabaccount', 'addaccount'],
                                      ['#tabuser', 'addusers'],
                                      ['#tabadd','adddomain'] ],
                    :linkactions => [ [] ],
                    :filteractions => [ [] ] }
      when :none 
        @actions = {}
      #when 
      #  @actions = {}
      else
        @actions = @actions
      end
    end  


    def dashcontroller
      {:title => @title, :instance => @instance, :actions => @actions }
    end

  end
end
```

So basically I just need to pass an instance of `this.dashcontroller` and I get the hash I need with a lot less chaos in my controllers . The issue is with the `@instance` variable. I want to pass in the instance I'm using e.g. `@book`, `@account`, etc, and have it come out as `@book`, `@account`, etc. Instead, I get the contents of whatever I put into there  as `:instance => (contents of that instance)`. It doesn't seem right to me as before I was just using e.g. `@account`, and then using that, but looking at it might not make any sort of difference in the widget, as I juggle things and work on my code-fu.

Basically my question is how to push an instance variable through a class like this, and still have it accessibile as it went in without having to do any backflips and transformations on the other side. There is probably a better way, but this is what I'm working with at the moment.

edit: pseudo-code

```
DashControl::DashControl.new("Catchy Title", @book, :none).dashcontroller
#=> {:title => "Catchy Title", :instance => @book, :actions => {} }
```

I think I can work with it, like I said its more an issue of my understanding of how things flow than an actual bug or anything difficult. I'd like to not have to do more gymnastics on the other end with the instance stuff, though the contents are there and that is all I really need, I just need some input on thinking it through to be less of a mess. I really need to refine what I'm sending through this, or use this to further refine what I'm sending on is the bottom line lesson to take away right now.

edit:

I ended up tossing this, but it was a learning experience...I went back the widget and I know more than when I originally set up the widget, so I've been able to set that up to take only the instance variable and bootstrap what it needs without adding another class, cleaning up my controllers and handing a lot back to the widget where I suspect it should/could have been to start.

Comment: Can you give a pseudocode example of how you want this to ultimately appear? Like, what do you want to pass to your function and what do you want the result to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your code and example, this fits:

```
# No need to put a class in a namespace of the same name, just make the module a class
# Also, if you inherit from a struct, it can save you a lot of typing. It defines the setters and getters for you.
class DashControl < Struct.new(:title, :instance, :actions)

  # since it looks like you always access it the same way, create a class method
  # which does this initialization and invocation
  def self.for(*args)
    new(*args).dashcontroller
  end

  def initialize(title='default title', instance='default instance', actions=:none)
    # here, we can use our own defaults and normalization and pass the results up to the struct
    super title, instance, normalize(actions)
  end

  # didn't make sense to call this initialize_tag, as it was initializing actions
  # also there was already an initialize actions method which just checked for the case of a hash
  # but then elsewhere you checked for other things. Better to just put it all in one method and return it
  # (then you aren't setting it every time you want to ask it to calculate that value)
  # also using guard clauses (the if statements that return early) instead of the case, as they are easier to understand
  def normalize(actions)
    return Hash.new if actions == :none
    return actions unless actions == :manage_default
    default_actions
  end  

  # the value of default_actions is complicated and noisy, separate it out to its own method
  # this prevents it from cluttering the code around it, and also allows us to access,
  # and to do this without the side effects of setting values.
  def default_actions
    { :statusactions => [], 
      :formactions   => [ ['#tabaccount', 'addaccount'],
                          ['#tabuser', 'addusers'],
                          ['#tabadd','adddomain'] ],
      :linkactions   => [ [] ],
      :filteractions => [ [] ] }
  end

  # use the getters instead of the ivars (I consider this a generally best practice -- and you could have
  # done it before, since you declared the attr_accessor, even though I'm accessing it through the struct)
  def dashcontroller
    {:title => title, :instance => instance, :actions => actions }
  end
end

DashControl.for                                           # => {:title=>"default title", :instance=>"default instance", :actions=>{}}
DashControl.for('Catchy Title', '@book', :none)           # => {:title=>"Catchy Title", :instance=>"@book", :actions=>{}}
DashControl.for('Catchy Title', '@book', :manage_default) # => {:title=>"Catchy Title", :instance=>"@book", :actions=>{:statusactions=>[], :formactions=>[["#tabaccount", "addaccount"], ["#tabuser", "addusers"], ["#tabadd", "adddomain"]], :linkactions=>[[]], :filteractions=>[[]]}}
DashControl.for('Catchy Title', '@book', a: 'b')          # => {:title=>"Catchy Title", :instance=>"@book", :actions=>{:a=>"b"}}
DashControl.for('Catchy Title', '@book', 123)             # => {:title=>"Catchy Title", :instance=>"@book", :actions=>123}
```

Comment: I've read about OpenStruct, but have never used it. This provides more to think about and I can add to what I'm building. 'getters instead of ivars'....I'm still certain how exactly to build a class and manage variables effectively, or even what is the ruby way, only what has worked so far for me as I'm learning. I do like the self.for, which is useful for doing more by saying less which I can put to use. Thanks.

Comment: Just re-read the code, the struct is superfluous. I think I put it in early on, but then as I implemented more, wound up needing to introduce the initialize method in order to provide default values, and then wound up needing to specify the values to super in order to normalize them. At that point, I should have switched back to attr_accessor. The initialize will have to call the setters instead of super, but none of the other code changes, since it still uses getters, and so it is agnostic to things like whether they're in ivars or whatever struct uses.